# Recursive function using pthreads in C

Tags: c, recursion, pthreads

I have the following piece of code

```
    #include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBINS 8


void swap_long(unsigned long int **x, unsigned long int **y){

  unsigned long int *tmp;
  tmp = x[0];
  x[0] = y[0];
  y[0] = tmp;

}

void swap(unsigned int **x, unsigned int **y){

  unsigned int *tmp;
  tmp = x[0];
  x[0] = y[0];
  y[0] = tmp;

}

void truncated_radix_sort(unsigned long int *morton_codes, 
              unsigned long int *sorted_morton_codes, 
              unsigned int *permutation_vector,
              unsigned int *index,
              int *level_record,
              int N, 
              int population_threshold,
              int sft, int lv){

  int BinSizes[MAXBINS] = {0};
  unsigned int *tmp_ptr;
  unsigned long int *tmp_code;

  level_record[0] = lv; // record the level of the node

  if(N<=population_threshold || sft < 0) { // Base case. The node is a leaf
    memcpy(permutation_vector, index, N*sizeof(unsigned int)); // Copy the pernutation vector
    memcpy(sorted_morton_codes, morton_codes, N*sizeof(unsigned long int)); // Copy the Morton codes 

    return;
  }
  else{

    // Find which child each point belongs to 
    int j = 0;
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
      unsigned int ii = (morton_codes[j]>>sft) & 0x07;
      BinSizes[ii]++;
    }


    // scan prefix 
    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAXBINS; i++){
      int ss = BinSizes[i];
      BinSizes[i] = offset;
      offset += ss;
    }

    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
      unsigned int ii = (morton_codes[j]>>sft) & 0x07;
      permutation_vector[BinSizes[ii]] = index[j];
      sorted_morton_codes[BinSizes[ii]] = morton_codes[j];
      BinSizes[ii]++;
    }

    //swap the index pointers  
    swap(&index, &permutation_vector);

    //swap the code pointers 
    swap_long(&morton_codes, &sorted_morton_codes);

    /* Call the function recursively to split the lower levels */
    offset = 0; 
    for(i=0; i<MAXBINS; i++){

      int size = BinSizes[i] - offset;

      truncated_radix_sort(&morton_codes[offset], 
               &sorted_morton_codes[offset], 
               &permutation_vector[offset], 
               &index[offset], &level_record[offset], 
               size, 
               population_threshold,
               sft-3, lv+1);
      offset += size;  
    }


  } 
}
```

I tried to make this block

```
int j = 0;
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
      unsigned int ii = (morton_codes[j]>>sft) & 0x07;
      BinSizes[ii]++;
    }
```

parallel by substituting it with the following

```
    int rc,j;
    pthread_t *thread = (pthread_t *)malloc(NTHREADS*sizeof(pthread_t));
    belong *belongs = (belong *)malloc(NTHREADS*sizeof(belong));
    pthread_mutex_init(&bin_mtx, NULL);
    for (j = 0; j < NTHREADS; j++){
        belongs[j].n = NTHREADS;
        belongs[j].N = N;
        belongs[j].tid = j;
        belongs[j].sft = sft;
        belongs[j].BinSizes = BinSizes;
        belongs[j].mcodes = morton_codes;
        rc = pthread_create(&thread[j], NULL, belong_wrapper, (void *)&belongs[j]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < NTHREADS; j++){
        rc = pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
    }
```

and defining these outside the recursive function

```
typedef struct{
    int n, N, tid, sft;
    int *BinSizes;
    unsigned long int *mcodes;
}belong;

pthread_mutex_t bin_mtx;

void * belong_wrapper(void *arg){
    int n, N, tid, sft, j;
    int *BinSizes;
    unsigned int ii;
    unsigned long int *mcodes;
    n = ((belong *)arg)->n;
    N = ((belong *)arg)->N;
    tid = ((belong *)arg)->tid;
    sft = ((belong *)arg)->sft;
    BinSizes = ((belong *)arg)->BinSizes;
    mcodes = ((belong *)arg)->mcodes;
    for (j = tid; j<N; j+=n){
        ii = (mcodes[j] >> sft) & 0x07;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bin_mtx);
        BinSizes[ii]++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bin_mtx);
    }

}
```

However it takes a lot more time than the serial one to execute... Why is this happening? What should I change?

Comment: If all the threads are mutexed continually then there is zero benefit to threading (you are basically serializing them). If however you could make each thread target a unique range of the array(s) and remove the mutex then each thread will be free to execute unhindered on its range and you should get improvements

Comment: The lock means that I just don't allow any other thread to write on the value I'm updating. In fact https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexLocking uses a similar technique except for that the function there is not recursive

Comment: You'll note that code accumulates some non-zero amount of work in un-synchronized local variables in each thread. You're synchronizing every increment.

Comment: I understand. I don't know the algorithm so cannot comment on it. However you do the lock/unlock at every iteration of the for loop. Meaning every thread, at every iteration of the for loop is being forced to stop and wait for other threads. If the lock/unlock was outside the loop, for example, you would get a speed boost - but I do not know the effect on your algorithm

Comment: Where exactly is the recursion? The posted code shows no evidence of any. And it would seem to me that mutex lock+unlock is doing little that a properly lockless interlocked increment wouldn't handle. You said, "The lock means that I just don't allow any other thread to write on the value I'm updating." That isn't accurate. That mutex means no other thread can update **any** value while you're incrementing the current value, *regardless* of whether they're trying to update the same value or not.

Comment: I suspect that an interlocked increment would still cost more than the tiny amount of code that is actually concurrent, though. It's just the loop and the morton array operations - probably < 10 instructions in total.

Comment: @Useless you may be right. My point is multiple threads updating *different* slot values would not reach barrier contention as they do with that performance-choking single global mutex.

Comment: @Chris,@Useless I updated the code...Thanks for taking the time to look into this...I am a noob in pthreads and I am barely getting what you are talking about...So forgive me If I don't respond appropriately!

Comment: Picture threading like tanks of water. You have 8 tanks of water with taps. You want to feed 80 people from the tanks. If you only have one cup, you will force serial: turn on tap to fill one cup and turn it off again. Slow. If you have 8 cups you can turn 8 taps on at once, fill 8 cups at once, turn all 8 taps off. faster. If you have a 80 cups, you can turn the taps on and let the taps drain and fill all cups. fastest. When you put a mutex in the for loop, you have only one cup. Mutex is used to prevent threads doing things at the same time. May as well have one super huge tank, same speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a single mutex to guard updates to the `BinSizes` array, you're still ultimately doing all the updates to this array sequentially: only one thread can call `BinSizes[ii]++` at any given time.  Basically you're still executing your function in sequence but incurring the extra overhead of creating and destroying threads.

There are several options I can think of for you (there are probably more):

1. do as @Chris suggests and make each thread update one portion of
   `BinSizes`.  This might not be viable depending on the properties of
   the calculation you're using to compute `ii`.
2. Create multiple mutexes representing different partitions of
   `BinSizes`.  For example, if `BinSizes` has 10 elements, you could
   create one mutex for elements 0-4, and another for elements 5-9,
   then use them in your thread something like so:

   ```
   if (ii < 5) {
     mtx_index = 0;
   } else {
     mtx_index = 1;
   }
   pthread_mutex_lock(&bin_mtx[mtx_index]);
   BinSizes[ii]++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&bin_mtx[mtx_index]);
   ```

   You could generalize this idea to any size of BinSizes and any range:
   Potentially you could have a different mutex for each array element.  Of course
   then you're opening yourself up to the overhead of creating each of these mutexes, and 
   the possibility of deadlock if someone tries to lock several of them at once etc...
3. Finally, you could abandon the idea of parallelizing this block altogether: as other users have mentioned using threads this way is subject to some level of diminishing returns.  Unless your `BinSizes` array is very large, you might not see a huge benefit to parallelization even if you "do it right".

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - adding threads isn't a trivial fix for most problems. Yours isn't embarassingly parallelizable, and this code has hardly any actual concurrency.

---

You spin a mutex for every (cheap) integer operation on `BinSizes`. This will crush any parallelism, because all your threads are serialized on this.

The few instructions you *can* run concurrently (the for loop and a couple of operations on the morton code array) are *much* cheaper than (un)locking a mutex: even using an atomic increment (if available) would be more expensive than the un-synchronized part.

One fix would be to give each thread its own output array, and combine them after all tasks are complete.

Also, you create and join multiple threads per call. Creating threads is relatively expensive compared to computation, so it's generally recommended to create a long-lived pool of them to spread that cost.

Even if you do this, you need to tune the number of threads according to how many (free) cores do you have. If you do this in a recursive function, how many threads exist at the same time? Creating more threads than you have cores to schedule them on is pointless.

Oh, and you're leaking memory.